# Calculate logarithm for whole column excel

Tags: excel, vba

let us suppose we have following image :
[image]

i want to calculate  logarithm for  A column, i wrote  following code which will calculate log of  each A value  and write  inside A column, here is my code :

```
Private Sub Log_transform_Click()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:A41")

For Each cell In rng
cell.Value = Log(cell.Value)
Next cell



End Sub
```

my question is : how to write result in B column?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- One option without looping
- Set formula first and then convert to values

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        ' Set formula
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=LOG(RC[-1])"
        ' Covert formula to value, if you need
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so connection between  B column and A column is  represented by this line right?LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("B2:B" & LastRow)

Comment: `LastRow` is the row # of last line. `Range("B2:B" & LastRow)` is the range which is filled in col B.

Answer (score 1):

I  got  following solution -the main idea was that like a python or matlab, that ar  vectorised  programming languages,  if i can apply the same principle here, if i will do it mannualy with for loop, solution is that :

```
Private Sub Log_transform_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim n   As Integer


Set rng = Range("A2:A41")
n = WorksheetFunction.Count(rng)
For i = 2 To n + 1
Cells(i, 2).Value = Log(Cells(i, 1))


Next i



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In Excel VBA, in general, it takes much longer to access worksheet cells to manipulate them than it does to do the work in a VBA array. (five times as long in many of my measurements).

If you are going to do the calculations in VBA, I would recommend reading the range into an array (one step); doing the calculations, then writing the results back (also in a single step).

The coding is more complex, but execution time is much faster.

For example, for your problem, assuming data starts in `A1` of a worksheet:

```
Option Explicit
Sub logs()
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim v As Variant, I As Long
    
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6") 'or whatever worksheet
    Set rSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    v = rSrc 'v will be a 2D array
End With
    
For I = 2 To UBound(v, 1) 'start at 2 to avoid column header
    v(I, 1) = Log(v(I, 1)) / Log(10#)
Next I
v(1, 1) = "Log(Price)"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rSrc.Offset(columnoffset:=1)
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = v
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Of course, if you use a Table, you can simply enter a formula in the first cell of the `Log(Price)` column and the formula will fill down automagically:

```
=LOG([@Price])
```

Note that VBA `Log` function returns the natural log, whereas the Excel worksheet function `LOG` returns the base-10 log. Hence the VBA formula is a bit different to return the same result.

Comment: For more information on passing arrays to/from the worksheet, if it is still active, see the late Chip Pearson's web page on [VBA Arrays and worksheet ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: It seems a dot is missing in `Set rSrc = .Range( )`.

Comment: @taller I guess I am not understanding something as I disagree. Please share the circumstance **you tested** under which this made a difference.

Comment: Here are my thoughts, although it might be overthinking. Assuming there are two sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet6) in the workbook. It raises a 1004 error when the code is stored in Sheet1's module (which, of course, is not the best practice). Otherwise, your code works well and answers the OP's question.

Comment: @taller The code should be in a regular module. To write code on the chance that someone might store it in some other place seems inefficient. Better to educate that person. If the code were being stored in an add-in, it would also need some changes, but I'd think someone knowledgeable enough to do that would also know what changes are required.

Answer (score 1):

Below output Log(A_column); depends on the context in case you meant *natural logarithm (ln)* instead, replace `Cells(i, 2).Value = Log(Cells(i, 1).Value)` as `Cells(i, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Ln(Cells(i, 1).Value)`.

```
Sub CalcLog()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 1).Value > 0 Then
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Log(Cells(i, 1).Value)
        Else
            MsgBox "error: value < 0"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

e.g. outputs,

[image]